# Sun is giving new energy everyday. Then how does this phrase make any sense: "Energy is never created nor destroyed, only transformed"?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, earth, sun

If sun is the source of energy on earth, then this means that the sun is providing new energy everyday. Then how does this phrase does make any sense: "Energy is never created nor destroyed, only transformed"? 
Because if all the functions of earth is going on by a fixed energy, only transforming one into another, then what about the new energy coming everyday from the sun?

Comment: The sun loses energy by the second, however It's not creating new energy, The star will, in the far future lose it's energy and become a white dwaf.

Comment: question is about Earth @DouglasD.Beatenhead
and ok i understand sun but, from where the first energy came?

Answer (score 5):

Within the star (our sun) fusion reactions take place in it's core to generate radiation. To go into this properly you need to know about nuclear fusion but basically the binding energy released when helium is produced in the sun is *transformed* (mostly) to photon energy (radiation).

It is the energy of this radiation that the earth is receiving.

There is much more to it than this and I don't want to give an over complicated answer.

---

### Edit:

@PM 2Ring has given you a good explanation of where the energy goes in the comment below. I will just expand a little on a point made in that comment since you are asking 'where does the energy go after leaving earth?'

Basically, this process of 'absorption and re-emission' of the radiation (described in the comment) will continue with other bodies in space after the radiation has left the earth.

So you may be wondering at this point; Where does the energy all go in the end? I don't have a good answer to this and I don't know if such an answer even exists.

However, I can tell you that **most** energy is transformed to heat (energy) *eventually*.

Comment: Question is about Earth. new energy coming everyday from sun. so who earth giving to?

Comment: @MAshrafulA Some of the sunlight reaching Earth is immediately reflected back to space. Some of the Sun's energy is temporarily stored on Earth, eg in the form of heat, wind, chemical energy (both  inorganic and in living things). The Earth radiates a lot of energy into space as infrared radiation. Most of that energy is from the sunlight, but some is from the breakdown of radioactive elements within the Earth (principally uranium & thorium). And some of that lost heat is a remnant of the heat of the Earth's formation.

Answer (score 1):

> Then how does this phrase does make any sense: "Energy is never
>   created nor destroyed, only transformed"?

Within the sun's core, energy is *released* (transformed) via nuclear fusion.

There is no energy creation; [the sun loses roughly 4.2 *billion* kilograms of mass each second](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/users/acowie/class05/home7_sol.html) via this energy transformation.